# what do I replace get_bloginfo with and where do I find all instances of it?

Tags: php

I'm viewing the error log for something else when I see this:

PHP Notice:  get_bloginfo was called with an argument that is **deprecated** since version 2.2! The `siteurl` option is deprecated for the family of `bloginfo()` functions. Use the `url` option instead. in /home/blahblah/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line xxxx

In the wp-includes/functions.php file I see 2 instances of get_bloginfo:

```
header( "Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=" . get_bloginfo( 'charset' ) );
```

and

```
function wp_nonce_ays( $action ) {
if ( 'log-out' == $action ) {
    $html = sprintf( __( 'You are attempting to log out of %s' ), get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ) . '</p><p>';
```

Instance #1 I can just replace get_bloginfo with url?

Instance #2 .. not sure what I should replace it with.

Question #3: would this error exist anywhere else on the site or just in wp-includes/functions.php?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `wp-includes/functions.php` is where the error message is being generated, it's not what is triggering the error. the error message should mention the actual theme or plugin file where the function that generates the error was called, you should absolutely not edit `wp-includes/functions.php`.

Comment: The error message does not mention any theme/plugin file. What I posted above (with some editing) is what the actual message is. fyi the line number is 3842.

Comment: I suggest starting with your theme and plugins then and searching for instances of `get_bloginfo`. If you look at line 3842 you'll see that's where the error message originates, but what triggered it won't be found in that or any other WP core file.

Answer (score 2):

Deprecated arguments include:

- ‘siteurl’ – Use ‘url’ instead
- ‘home’ – Use ‘url’ instead

Based on the information at [`get_bloginfo`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_bloginfo/), you should be able to use `get_bloginfo('url')`.

What line number is being referenced in [`/wp-includes/functions.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.5-branch/wp-includes/functions.php)?